# How to get the maximum number of threads my program has used?

Tags: linux, multithreading, macos, pthreads, profiling

I'm attempting to profile the system resources used by my application.   My application is using threads as well as 3rd party libraries which may also be using threads.  Is there a way to find out the following?

- The total number of threads ever created in my process
- The maximum number of concurrent threads that were created in my process

Operating System is Linux or macOS.  I'm looking for preferably source-level solutions.  My application is in Swift, but I'm okay with C, command-line, or really any practical solution.  Also since I'm using 3rd party libraries, I cannot simply write wrapper functions around the thread creation functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for this, you can look at the structure of processes with
All subprocesses will be listed

In Bash:

```
pstree
```

or first get the pid of your programm first and:

```
pstree $(pidof appname)
```

Comment: I believe ps and pstree will only give you a live snapshot of threads.  But I want to know the total number of threads ever created in my program, including threads that have been destroyed.